# Strtime returning wrong date time

Tags: php, datetime

I have this simple PHP function:

```
<?php

$start_date = strtotime('-7 days', '2014-06-04 00:00:00');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date);

?>
```

This returns 1969-12-24 18:33:34. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Second argument should be a unix timestamp, not a string.... it's casting `'2014-06-04 00:00:00'` to integer giving `2014`, treating 2014 as the unix timestamp value, then subtracting 7 days from that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not having read the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the [second argument](https://www.php.net/strtotime) Unix Timestamp.

```
$start_date = strtotime('-7 days', strtotime('2014-06-04 00:00:00'));
```

In fact you can also get away with

```
$start_date = strtotime('2014-06-04 00:00:00 -7 days');
```